# how to get "real" url from img src in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have piece of offline html like so:

```
<img src="../img/button.png"/>
```

and when I try to access the src attribute in JS, I get a different value than what's written in the html:

```
var s = myimg.src; // equals 'file:///V:/test/test1/img/button.png'
```

It's as if the value got resolved somewhere between the html and my call to 'src' attribute. How do I get the "original" value instead of the resolved one?

tnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `getAttribute`

```
var s = myimg.getAttribute('src')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the attribute instead of the `src` property, you get the original value:

```
var s = myimg.getAttribute('src');
```